# DateTime Math 2 Hours Or Greater Since confirmation_sent_at Rails Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-confirmable

Time and date math always seems to get the best of me. I want to write a check to verify it's been 2 hours or more since we sent the original devise confirmation email.

I've tried different variations trying to use DateTime and time etc and I cannot figure it out and could use some help. confirmation_sent_at is a DateTime I believe. EX: `Tue, 17 May 2022 20:47:51.290039000 UTC +00:00.`

How do I check if its been >= 2 hours since current_user.confirmation_sent_at . For testing purposes I've been using minutes and seconds fwiw 2.minutes.ago, 2.hours.ago etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example now is 10:00

And for example confirmation for `user1` was sent in 9:00, for `user2` in 5:00

Using `<`

```
user1.confirmation_sent_at < 2.hours.ago # => false
user2.confirmation_sent_at < 2.hours.ago # => true
```

And using `>`

```
user1.confirmation_sent_at > 2.hours.ago # => true
user2.confirmation_sent_at > 2.hours.ago # => false
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, im messing around with your solution in irb and I always get true for <.

Comment: This is correct frick sakes, it was my data. I was expecting devise to update confirmation_sent_at like it was with our other mailers but it wasnt, so im doing it and now it works, thank you!